# How to show CSS background color on top of an inline style background image

Tags: html, css

I am using laravel so I cant put a background image into my css style sheet or I loose my variable. So here is how I have it now

```
<div class="gradient"><div class="topback" style="background-image: url('/storage/cover_images/{{$post->cover_image}}') ; background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: center center; ">
```

I am trying to do a gradient overlay ontop of the background-image in the gradient class. The issue is no matter what I do, the gradient class wont show up on top of the image. I have even used zindex to try.

Anyone know a solution where I don't have to put the background-image in my css? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use multiple background on the needed element:

```css
.topback {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topback" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0.5),yellow), url('https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=1069') ; background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: center center; ">
```

If you want one color:

```css
.topback {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topback" style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,200,0,0.5),rgba(0,200,0,0.5)), url('https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=1069') ; background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: center center; ">
```